# How can I limit the login attempts using redis?

Tags: design-patterns, redis

I'm implementing a block to my logins so if many (10?) failed logins occur (like someone trying to brute force a password) that account cannot try to log-in for a few minutes (even with the valid password)...

I though of a rate limiting patter using Redis, and in redis.io they offer two possible implementations: [Pattern: Rate limiter](http://redis.io/commands/INCR)

But they give problems to both, especially in case of concurrency or lost command.

What solution do you recommend?

Answer (score -1):

I have found a possible solution. This is the pseudo-code:

```
FUNCTION LIMIT_API_CALL(key):
value = INCR(key)
IF value > 10 THEN
    ERROR "too many requests"
ELSE
    EXPIRE(key, blockedTime)
    PERFORM_API_CALL()
END
```

This seems to shift the problem slightly compared to the linked implementations in redis.io, but i think it is robust to the problems stated so there is no memory leak, and a TTL is always set even if one of the commands fails.

EDIT (a year later):

This trick has been deployed in production, with the following addition to solve the problem detected in the first comment:

A successful return of PERFORM_API_CALL deletes the key, resetting the expiration counter:

```
FUNCTION LIMIT_API_CALL(key):
value = INCR(key)
IF value > 10 THEN
    ERROR "too many requests"
ELSE
    IF (PERFORM_API_CALL())
        DEL(key)
    ELSE
        EXPIRE(key, blockedTime)
END
```

Comment: This appears to be a nice simple and fast bit of code. I think it may run into some issues that have nothing to do with race conditions or coding flaws. For example, if you only want to allow "10 login attempts per hour", but the user attempts to login only once every 30 minutes, in 5 hours they will be denied a login attempt for another full hour - that behaviour is more like "2 login attempts per hour" before denying service. Another scenario: from the first login attempt to the 9th, almost an entire hour passes, but the user can still only attempt once more in the entire next hour.

Comment: You are of course right. However that problem was detected and solved by this very simple trick: after a successful login, the key is removed (and failures reset), so only failures trigger the increasing expiring counter. This allows for an attacker to try more combination if he knows WHEN a successful login will occur, but he can only double the rate for every successful login per expiration unit.... which won't happen much in the real world.